# No store found - Redux RevTools

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

It seems that I can not track down the states and actions of my app using the Redux DevTools. I am getting that **no store found** message.

Here is my code in App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import productsReducer from './store/reducers/products';
import cartReducer from './store/reducers/cart';
import ordersReducers from './store/reducers/orders';

import ShopNavigator from './navigation/ShopNavigator';

import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  orders: ordersReducers
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());

export default function App() {

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
  })

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading/>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ShopNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

And my package.json file

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.6.0",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION** && window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**() instead of composeWithDevTools() I hope it works

```
import React from 'react';

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import productsReducer from './store/reducers/products';
import cartReducer from './store/reducers/cart';
import ordersReducers from './store/reducers/orders';

import ShopNavigator from './navigation/ShopNavigator';

import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  orders: ordersReducers
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

export default function App() {

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
  })

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading/>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ShopNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```